# Join expression not supported SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, vba

```
SELECT 
    Trs.itemID, Trs.imtName, Trs.sumQty,  Sum(whiQty) 
FROM 
    ((SELECT 
          trsitemID AS itemID, trsimtName AS imtName, 
          Sum(trsQty) As sumQty 
      FROM 
          tblTransactionSub AS T 
      WHERE 
          trstraID = 1231 
          AND trsActive = True  
      GROUP BY 
          trsitemID, trsimtName) AS Trs 
INNER JOIN 
   tblWarehouseItem AS WHI ON Trs.itemID = WHI.whiitemID)
RIGHT JOIN 
   WHI ON Trs.trswhiID = WHI.whiID 
WHERE 
    whiActive = True 
    AND whiCansel = False  
    AND whiwrhID = 19 
GROUP BY 
    Trs.itemID,Trs.imtName, Trs.sumQty 
HAVING 
    SUM(whiQty) < Trs.sumQty
```

If you please help me me out since I am new to SQL commands I can not easily find my mistake.

Thanks in advance

The error that occurred when I added the `Right Join` is:

> Join expression not supported

Comment: what is the exact error?

Comment: The `RIGHT JOIN` has to have a **table name** (or a subselect) associated with it, to which you join your existing rows....

Comment: if i add "RIGHT JOIN tblWarehouseItem" i have an error: JOIN expression not supported

Comment: You can't first INNER JOIN on WHI and then RIGHT JOIN that on WHI again. If you want to join on the same table again, you have to use another instance of it. When you tried tblWarehouseitem, did you also change the WHI.whiitemID?

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access, you have to use parenthesises with multiple joins:

```
select ...
from 
    ((table1
    ... join table2 on ...)
    ... join table3 on ...)
    ... join tableN
```

/edit/

As OP question changes its syntax often, then my answer seems out of place :) Initially there were no parens there.

About RIGHT JOIN: You need to use table name (or entire subselect) after JOIN keyword, not skip it or use some other alias. Your query part

```
RIGHT JOIN 
    WHI ON Trs.trswhiID = WHI.whiID
```

currently uses alias WHI, which is wrong in two ways: 1) it is not table name 2) it is already used. You need something like this:

```
RIGHT JOIN 
    tblWarehouseItem AS WHI2 ON Trs.trswhiID = WHI2.whiID
```

It could be possible that MS Access restricts your kind of JOINs usage (like INNER join should not come after LEFT join); I have currently no possibility to check precise rules.

Comment: I am pretty sure you problem comes from your parenthesis and that Arvo's answer is the correct one

Comment: Missing table name after RIGHT JOIN is of course error too, but this was noted in other answers already.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have no table name after the `RIGHT JOIN`:

```
RIGHT JOIN 
   ON Trs.trswhiID = WHI.whiID
```

Should be:

```
RIGHT JOIN YOURTABLENAMEHERE as alias
   ON Trs.trswhiID = WHI.whiID
```

However, you have already defined `Trs` and `Whi`, so I have no idea what table you want there, or why.  Perhaps you just want to change the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN`.